# Jquery show second tab as default active

Tags: jquery, tabs

I'm trying to display my second li tag as default active tab.
My jquery code is

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#newtabs div').hide();
        $('#newtabs div:first').show();
        $('#newtabs ul li:first').addClass('active');
        $('#newtabs ul li a').click(function(){ 
            $('#newtabs ul li').removeClass('active');
            $(this).parent().addClass('active'); 
            var currentTab = $(this).attr('href'); 
            $('#newtabs div').hide();
            $(currentTab).show();
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Any suggestion to do this?

Comment: Please show us your markup too.

Comment: Or can you create a JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#newtabs div').hide();
    $('#newtabs div').eq(1).show();
    $('#newtabs ul li').eq(1).addClass('active');
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 3):

According to the jQuery documentation (http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/), you can use the `active` attribute when setting up the options. For example, you can do

```
$(".selector").tabs({ active: 1 });
```

This would set the second tab (based on a 0 index).

Comment: I don't see him using the UI tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
$('#newtabs ul li:first').addClass('active');
```

try

```
$('#newtabs ul li').eq(1).addClass('active');
```

This provided that #newtabs only contains one ul. If there are more than one ul inside #newtabs that you want to target, you need to use

```
$('#newtabs ul li:nth-child(2)').addClass('active');
```

as that selects "all li elements that are the second child of their parent" (nth-child() uses 1-based indexing), while the other approach will select the second li child of the first ul only.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you should just change

```
$('#newtabs div:first').show();
$('#newtabs ul li:first').addClass('active');
```

into

```
$('#newtabs div:eq(1)').show();
$('#newtabs ul li:eq(1)').addClass('active');
```

That `eq(1)` filters the 2th object (indexes start at 0)

Comment: You mean it filters the second object (which is what he wants too).

Comment: That's right. I should have said that it filters the object at index 1, thus the second object.

Comment: Then I'm not sure if the second li is also inside the second div, as you suggest, but then again we're only guessing what the actual markup is :)